# PHP retrieving variables from a large SQL result set

Tags: php, sql

I have been working on my own PHP project. I have hit an obstacle. I am trying to retrieve the results of a database and print out a form for each result set.

I then wish to interact with one particular result either be deleting it or passing it into a function etc..

Heres is my current code :

```
    <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<div id="post">'; ?>
                <form action="" method="post">
            <?php
                echo "<font size=4>".$row['post']."<br>"; 
                echo "posted by : ".$row['username']."<br>";
                $id = $row['p_id']; ?>
                <input type="submit" name="choice" value="Y">
                <input type="submit" name="choice" value="N">
                </form>
                <br>
                </div>
            }
    <?php
    if($_POST['choice']=="Y"){
     // progress
     functionA();
    }
    else if($_POST['choice']=="N"){
     // delete or remove
     functionB();
    }
 ?>
```

So my goal here would be click Y to progress that particular result or N to delete/remove the result.
However currently by clicking either button all results either get deleted or progress. I do know that the id should be used to differentiate between posts but I cant quite seem to get it to work. Once the button is pressed it passes all results to either function.

Comment: I see that you are ending your PHP tag `?>` then you have PHP code but without an opening PHP tag :  `<?php` is this your actual code?

Comment: @CodeGodie no sorry this was just a snippet of the code. I have editied the above to have better structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suppose you want to know the record to delete. So, add an input to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>">
```

Then, in your script, call:

```
if( $_POST['choice'] == "Y" )
{
    // progress
    functionA( $_POST['id'] );
}
elseif( $_POST['choice']=="N" )
{
    // delete or remove
    functionB( $_POST['id'] );
}
```

Additional problem: how you can use your db connection [inside the functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)? Assuming your mysqli connection is named `$conn`, call the function(s) in this way:

```
functionA( $_POST['id'], $conn );
```

Side note: **First** process `$_POST` values, **then** retrieve db records and print it.

Side note 2: take a look at [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli.prepare.php).

---

- Read more about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
- Read more about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had dumbed my code down in an attempt to make it work. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use two different `<input type="radio">`s for each item with the id in the value and let the user select which to delete and which to process.

So for an item with id `1` the outputted HTML would look like:

`<input type="radio" name="items[1]" value="delete"><input type="radio" name="items[1]" value="process">`

The `name` forces the items to go to `_POST` as an array with the ids as keys and the selected action as their values.

Example html: https://jsfiddle.net/gu1gkwod/

Comment: thank you very much for your help you both have saved me allot of time.

Comment: You're welcome. In your code above there's a `}` that's outside the PHP tags btw :)